# Can neutron magnetic moment be used to slightly deflect the neutrons to not hit the tocamac lattice at a really small angle?

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, fusion, neutrons

Can neutron magnetic moment be used to slightly deflect the neutrons to not hit the tocamac lattice at a small angle? So part of the moment is spent to change its velocity vector orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neutron’s magnetic moment is about fifty nano-eV per tesla. So-called “ultra-cold” neutrons, with energies below a hundred nano-eV, can be expelled from regions with tesla-scale magnetic fields. Mega-eV neutrons from fusion reactions cannot be substantially steered by laboratory fields.

Answer (score 3):

> tocamac lattice at a small angle

If you are referring to the material lattice of a tokamak machine: **NO**.

There's just no way. The magnetic moment is way too small.

Also, we don't want to. Those neutrons will be used to breed tritium which we need for fuel. This is done by surrounding the fusion with a "blanket" of lithium, which turns into tritium when it's hit by an energetic neutron. So those neutrons are valuable.

There is a serious engineering problem making a "first wall" that is relatively transparent to the neutrons while still being strong enough to hold a reactor together. This is an unsolved problem.